# Fluent NHibernate one to one mapping insert issue

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, foreign-key-relationship

One to one mapping works fine when retriving the values based on bellow mapping. But when inserting values

> unable to resolve property: MasterData

is thrown.

Tables are listed bellow

> MasterDataTable [MasterDataID (PK), Name ]
>
> OtherDataTable [MasterDataID (PK)(FK), OtherName]

Fluent NHibernare Classes are

```
Public class MasterData{
public virtual long MasterDataID {get;set;}
public virtual string Name {get;set;}
public virtual OtherData OtherDataProp {get;set;}
}

public class OtherData{
public virtual long MasterDataID {get;set;}
public virtual string OtherName {get;set;}
}

public class MasterDataMap: ClassMap<MasterData>{
 public MasterDataMap(){
 //table declaration

   Id(x => x.MasterDataID).Column("MasterDataID").GeneratedBy.gui.Sequence("MASTER_DATA_SEQ");
 Map(x => x.Name).Column("Name");
}
}

public class OtherDataMap: ClassMap<OtherData>{
 public OtherDataMap(){
 //table declaration

   Id(x => x.MasterDataID, "MASTER_DATA_ID").GeneratedBy.Foreign("MasterData")
 Map(x => x.Name).Column("OtherName");
}
}
```

Please let me know what other information is needed to resolve this. I am able to retrieve values but when i insert values i am not able.

Regards,
Desmond

Answer (score 0):

In your case, there will be a one-to-one mapping (there could be only one `MasterData` instance for a unique ID as well only one `OtherData`).
In this case the *slave* entity `OtherData` has also have to reference to its *master* `MasterData`

```
public class OtherData
{
  public virtual long MasterDataID {get;set;}
  public virtual string OtherName {get;set;}
  public virtual MasterData MasterData {get;set;}
}
```

Then we can follow this link to correctly map one-to-one:
https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping

#### MasterData

```
public MasterDataMap()
{
   Id(x => x.MasterDataID).Column("MasterDataID")
     .GeneratedBy.gui.Sequence("MASTER_DATA_SEQ");
   Map(x => x.Name).Column("Name");
   HasOne(x => x.OtherData);
}
```

#### OtherData

```
public OtherDataMap()
{
   Id(x => x.MasterDataID, "MasterDataID")
      .GeneratedBy.Foreign("MasterData")
   Map(x => x.OtherName).Column("OtherName"); // change from x.Name
   HasOne(x => x.MasterData);
}
```

What we are trying to achieve is to get this in XML

#### MasterData

```
 <class name="MasterData" ...>
  ...
  <one-to-one cascade="delete-orphan" lazy="proxy" name="OtherData />
  ..
 </class>
```

#### OtherData

```
<class name="OtherData" ...>    
  <id name="MasterDataID" column="MasterDataId">
    <generator class="foreign">
      <param name="property">MasterData</param>
    </generator>
  </id>
  <one-to-one name="MasterData" constrained="true" />
  ...
</class>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Yes i tried this way but the moment i referenced MasterData in the OtherData class due to the cyclic reference i am getting this "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly." I use the WCF service to retrieve data.

Comment: One more point. Even though with masterdata being referenced in the otherdata as you said. When i insert the record i am getting "attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property: MasterData". Sorry for trubling you but i hope this could help someone like me in the future.

Comment: This most likely would be caused by the fact that in C# was reference not set correctly. Other words there must be this both lines: **master.OtherData = slave; slave.MasterData = master;** This initialization must be don in the C# code, before it is persisted by NHibernate. When later, data are read, they will be set correctly. For insertion it must be done explicitly. Make sense?

Comment: In **One-to-one mapping** could not the slave live without master. Because NHibernate takes the master reference to find out the ID which will be reused. Please take a look here how it could be done http://marcinobel.com/index.php/fluent-nhibernate-mapping-one-to-on-relation/

Comment: I tried all the post and book reference and was not able to resolve. Since i was running out of time i made one to many relation and resolved the issue. Thank you for the effort. But i actually couldnt make out what you ment in the comments.

Comment: `MasterData` entity is a master, because its ID will be used as an ID for `OtherData`, which will act as a slave. *One-to-many* mapping could work if both entities have its own ID generator. I guess that it is working right now when you select them (because ID is assigned) but on insert you have to provide ID for `OtherData` which as the Schema in the snippet shows in your question - is dependent on `MasterData`. That's what I wante to say in comments ;)